# HTTPS broken up site?

Tags: magento

When we access our home page with https url site broken up. I think because the css, js load from http & it not secure.

But what should i do to run my site in both http & https.

Why this happen ? why this not solved in default magento?

for example [**https://demo.magentocommerce.com/**](https://demo.magentocommerce.com/)

Any help appreciated

Comment: check you secure skin url with  https://

Answer (score 0):

You need to set https for unsecure base url also in order to get the css load for https. I know you want to load site in both cases i.e. http and https, but using both URLs will cause your website's SEO to decrease.

Reason for this is:

http and https will be indexed in search engine as two different URLs.

Decision is up to you, whether you want to use http or https.